# What can I do in Rimworld after getting the basics set up?

Tags: rimworld

I've started playing Rimworld, and I'm finding it interesting, but I've run out of ideas for what I should do next. So far I've only got 3 colonists, I've setup housing for all of them, a mess hall, a trading beacon and power etc.

What I don't know is how to proceed from here. I can research, but what are some short term objectives I can aim for while this is happening? What are some longer term objectives?

Maybe another important thing is how can I get more colonists? I've read that I can buy slaves, or capture enemies, but I've not been attacked and the only slaver I saw came before I had a trading setup. Should I capture visitors perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're off to a good start next I'd get some defenses up, turrets and sandbags to be more specific. This will help with raider waves.

Which brings us to our next part: getting more people.

You can get people in 5 ways right now.

1. People will wander in and just join up no questions asked
2. An escape pod will crash and you will have to rescue the person and convince them to join
3. When fighting raiders, randomly the killing hit won't kill them only knock them unconscious. When this happens you have the ability to capture them
4. The same can be done for visitors
5. The same can be done for the people in cryo-sleep pods. A warning about this one though those pods are guarded by some hard to kill and hard hitting enemies open at your own risk

When you capture anyone you need to have prisoners beds set up for them to sleep in. I usually set these up away from my main colony just in case one breaks out. You then need to have a warden "try to recruit them" your chances are better if the person is not injured and well fed.

As from where to go from there you could outfit people with bionic parts, set up different productions to earn lots of sliver or build a rocket and escape the planet.

Comment: Some good points there, thanks for the information. How do I build the rocket to escape, I haven't found any information on it yet?

Comment: Keep researching stuff eventually you'll unlock the research for rocket parts

Answer (score 1):

While the given long term objective is to build a ship and leave the planet you are free to choose your own objectives. From building small little tree-huts to all your pawns with personal storage to become a huge cotton producer and earn money making superb quality touques. It's all about up to make your own story in Rimwolrd!

I had this very long-term objective once but then came this storm and a lightning started a fire to have 80% of my cotton crops burnt and two pawns with severs burns. Ouch..

My colony is leader producer of muffalo dusters and cobra skin cowboy hats!

Point is - there is no restraints - make your goal or let the random events make a story for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I understand that the idea is to make your own story, I'm more so looking for some basic objectives to fulfill. I'm yet to really learn the game, and I find it helpful to have some short term ideas. E.g. in an RTS the final objective is to crush the opponent; meantime you want to setup resource production, basic unit production, explore, setup research and build better units etc. So far I can't figure out what to do while I research.

Comment: Winter is coming! Well it depends on your location, but you might need to ensure you have food storage to cover cold months and enough power to keep temperature up in at least some buildings.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I suppose there will be plenty of smaller parts like this that I'll discover as I play